# Initializing array or Structure with zero causes misra violation to Rule11.9

Tags: c, misra

I am using Klocworks to check MISRA violations on C99.
When initializing an array of type u8(unsigned char) or a structure whose first element is of the same type, it shows a violation to MISRA Rule 11.9.

Example:

```
typedef unsigned char u8;

typedef {
  u8 a;
  u8 b;
  u8 c;
} tmyStruct;

const tmyStruct myStruct = { // MISRA.LITERAL.NULL.PTR.CONST.2012(Rule 11.9)
  .a = (u8)0,
  .b = (u8)0,
  .c = (u8)1
};
```

OR

```
typedef {
  u16 a;
  u8 b;
  u8 c;
} tmyStruct;

tmySructArr[3] =
{
 {
  .a = (u16)0,
  .b = (u8)0,
  .c = (u8)1
 },
 {
  .a = (u16)0,
  .b = (u8)0,
  .c = (u8)1
 },
 {
  .a = (u16)0,
  .b = (u8)0,
  .c = (u8)1
 },
};
```

Comment: Please quote the error and the rule.

Comment: If you need someone to quote the Rule, you won't be able to help...

Comment: You shouldn't need all those ugly casts - just `u` suffix all integer constants. That is `.a = 0u, .b = 0u, .c = 1u` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Rule 11.9 of MISRA C:2012 states

> The macro *NULL* shall be the only permitted form of integer *null*
> *pointer constant*.

While I see several zero value *constants*, I don't see any *pointers*, so I politely suggest that this is a false positive, and that you need to refer this to Klokwork/Perforce support.

PS: Please ditch the custom integer types, and use `<stdint.h>`

**Please note profile for my affiliations!**

Comment: I am afraid those custom types are defined inside micro libraries' header files. There are setbacks in the microcontroller world towards C++.